Add new frame with auto-keying every certain amount of frames (if possible)
I am not too sure if this is possible, but it sure would come in handy at times. I want to make a camera animation by enabling auto-keying and playing the animation while moving the camera around. I know that I could get smoother movement by just making the necessary keyframes for a basic straight line movement, and then just edit the animation in the graph editor. I really don't want to do this keyframe placement manually, though. Instead I want to move the camera in real time, making keyframes every so and so frames (say, 10). I am open to making a script that does this.
